# How can I configure the Pentaho files for LDAP/Active Directory?

Tags: ldap, pentaho

I'm configuring the Pentaho 6.1 server to work with LDAP for the first time.
Which parameters do I need to change? And how?

I've tried to follow the instructions on this manual page:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0P0/150/010/030

After I change "provider=jackrabbit" to "provider=ldap" in the file: security.properties, when I try to enter on the Pentaho Login page with the administrator user, I get an error like the user doesn't exist.

This is my actual LDAP parameters:

```
Server host: ldap-sweft.ferint.kabal
Server port: 389
Use TLS connection: no
Bind DN: zenit
Bind Password: asddsa
Users base DN: dc=ferint,dc=kabal
Enable Group Retrieval: yes
Search scope: subtree

User authentication:

User search filter: (&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=$USER$))
Identity Attribute: sAMAccountName
Get all users filter: (objectCategory=user)

Group support:

Users of group filter: (&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=$GROUP$))
Groups base DN: (vuoto)
Group Search Filter: (objectCategory=group)
Group Name Attribute: cn
Groups of user filter: (&(objectCategory=group)(member=$USER$))
```

---

This is how I changed the file: pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-security-ldap.properties

New file:

```
contextSource.providerUrl=ldap://ldap-sweft.ferint.kabal:389/
contextSource.userDn=dc\=ferint\\zenit
contextSource.password=asddsa

userSearch.searchBase=ou\=Utenti,dc\=ferint,dc\=kabal
userSearch.searchFilter=(sAMAccountName\={0})

populator.convertToUpperCase=false
populator.groupRoleAttribute=cn
populator.groupSearchBase=ou\=Gruppi,dc\=ferint,dc\=kabal
populator.groupSearchFilter=(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})
populator.rolePrefix=
populator.searchSubtree=true

allAuthoritiesSearch.roleAttribute=cn
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchBase=ou\=Gruppi,dc\=ferint,dc\=kabal
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchFilter=(objectClass\=organizationalRole)

allUsernamesSearch.usernameAttribute=sAMAccountName
allUsernamesSearch.searchBase=ou\=Utenti,dc\=ferint,dc\=kabal
allUsernamesSearch.searchFilter=objectClass\=person

adminRole=cn\=Administrator,ou\=roles
adminUser=cn\=zenit,ou\=Chiavi\ esoteriche,dc\=ferint,dc\=kabal
```

---

Original file:

```
contextSource.providerUrl=ldap\://localhost\:10389/ou\=system
contextSource.userDn=uid\=admin,ou\=system
contextSource.password=secret

userSearch.searchBase=ou\=users
userSearch.searchFilter=(cn\={0})

populator.convertToUpperCase=false
populator.groupRoleAttribute=cn
populator.groupSearchBase=ou\=roles
populator.groupSearchFilter=(roleOccupant\={0})
populator.rolePrefix=
populator.searchSubtree=false

allAuthoritiesSearch.roleAttribute=cn
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchBase=ou\=roles
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchFilter=(objectClass\=organizationalRole)

allUsernamesSearch.usernameAttribute=uid
allUsernamesSearch.searchBase=ou\=users
allUsernamesSearch.searchFilter=objectClass\=Person

adminRole=cn\=Administrator,ou\=roles
```

---

What parameters should I change?

- pentaho-solutions/system/data-access/settings.xml
- pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho.xml
- pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.properties
- pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml

Comment: Are you using Active Directory or another LDAP? Also, check the second line: "contextSource.userDn=dc\=ferint\\zenit" does not look like a valid DN. Something like the last line you have should work, though it's better to have a separate user to bind to LDAP i.m.o.

Comment: Yes, I'm using LDAP/MSAD. I access with: FERINT\F12345 or F12345 on my SSO.